# JsonSerializer seems to ignore timezone offset

Tags: c#, .net

I've been keeping on getting weird results in my tests, until I decided to perform some sanity checks, and found out to my surprise that:

```
    [TestCase("{\"a\":\"2020-11-11T11:11:10Z\"}", "{\"a\":\"2020-11-11T13:11:10+02:00\"}")]
    public void SanityCheck2(string jsonDateStringA, string jsonDateStringB)
    {
        DateTime schedule1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Temp>(jsonDateStringA).a;
        DateTime schedule2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Temp>(jsonDateStringB).a;

        Assert.That(schedule1, Is.EqualTo(schedule2));
    }
```

returned:

```
  Expected: 2020-11-11 13:11:10
  But was:  2020-11-11 11:11:10
```

Is this assertion reasonable? I need my models to take into account the time difference provided.
Or am I just doing the deserialization wrong?

Comment: Use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Do you mean I should change my model's field from `public DateTime Start` to `public DateTimeOffset Start`?

Comment: Read [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime) on this to see the difference. TLDR: If you care about offsets, always use `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Yes, change your model.

Comment: Well, this might just solved it, although braking several other tests that I'll have to fix. Thanks a lot!